# dataFrame keying using pandas groupby method

Tags: group-by, pandas

I new to pandas and trying to learn how to work with it. Im having a problem when trying to use an example I saw in one of wes videos and notebooks on my data. I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
filePath,vp,score
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_9709495726,-2
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_9708568031,-80
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_9702445777,-2
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_7023544759,-35
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_9702229339,-77
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_9513243289,25
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_2102513187,18
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_6625625104,-56
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_6073165338,-40
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_5105831247,-30
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_9513082770,-55
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_5753907026,-79
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_7403410322,11
E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav,Cust_4062144116,-70
```

I loading it to a data frame and the group it by "filePath" and "vp", the code is:

```
res = df.groupby(['filePath','vp']).size()    
res.index
```

and the output is:

```
[E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav                  Cust_2102513187,
Cust_4062144116,                                 Cust_5105831247,
Cust_5753907026,                                 Cust_6073165338,
Cust_6625625104,                                 Cust_7023544759,
Cust_7403410322,                                 Cust_9513082770,
Cust_9513243289,                                 Cust_9702229339,
Cust_9702445777,                                 Cust_9708568031,
Cust_9709495726]
```

Now Im trying to approach the index like a dict, as i saw in examples, but when im doing

```
res['Cust_4062144116']
```

I get an error:

```
KeyError: 'Cust_4062144116'
```

I do succeed to get a result when im putting the filepath, but as i understand and saw in previouse examples i should be able to use the vp keys as well, isnt is so?

Sorry if its a trivial one, i just cant understand why it is working in one example but not in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rutger you are not correct. It is possible to "partial" index a multiIndex series. I simply did it the wrong way.

The index first level is the file name (e.g. E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav above) and the second level is vp. Meaning, for each file name i have multiple vps. 
Now, this is correct:

```
res['E:\Audio\7168965711_5601_4.wav]
```

and will return:
Cust_2102513187 2
Cust_4062144116 8
....

but trying to index by the inner index (the Cust_ indexes) will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You groupby two columns and therefore get a MultiIndex in return. This means you also have to slice using those to columns, not with a single index value.

Your `.size()` on the groupby object converts it into a Series. If you force it in a DataFrame you can use the `.xs` method to slice a single level:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['filePath','vp']).size())
res.xs('Cust_4062144116', level=1)
```

That works. If you want to keep it as a series, boolean indexing can help, something like:

```
res[res.index.get_level_values(1) == 'Cust_4062144116']
```

The last option is a bit less readable, but sometimes also more flexibile, you could test for multiple values at once for example:

```
res[res.index.get_level_values(1).isin(['Cust_4062144116', 'Cust_6073165338'])]
```